# Pin lo in debug mode, but is hi in release mode, with no code change

Tags: pic, pic32

I have a PIC32MX695F512L project that works when in debug mode using a PicKit3, but not in release mode. Port F5 which is set as  an input pin is lo when using the debugger. But if I run it in release mode the pin goes hi. There is only a cable hooked up to it, which is lo. In release mode I can not read the lo. Any Idea why Port F5 goes high when in release mode?

Dennis

Comment: Could you please, post the source code? It could be that you have different preprocessor directives, making different setting on TRISF register in DEBUG or RELEASE mode, or different initialization, or something else. Without source code it is difficult to know... Also, check build configurations for DEBUG and RELEASE modes, especially optimization.

Comment: The source is exactly the the same in DEBUG mode and RELEASE mode.

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say release mode? Do you change compiler settings between debug and release? Do you unplug PicKit3? How the schematic for F5 connection looks, do you have pull-down? And finally are you sure that F5 is GPIO (are the all registers for peripherals that uses F5 set properly)? Without source code we can only guess.